# Finding the combination between 2 sets

Tags: combinatorics

8 balls are pulled at random from a bag of 32. Each ball is numbered 1-32.

Balls that are 1-16 go into set $S_1$.

> $x_i \in \{1,2,3...16\}$
>
> $S_1 = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\}$

Balls that are 17-32 go into set $S_2$.

> $y_i \in \{17,18,19...32\}$
>
> $S_2 = \{y_5, y_6, y_7, y_8\}$

To work out the number of possible combinations for $S_i$

> $k = 4$, $n = 16$.
>
> $\binom{16}{4}$ = 1820

But how do I find combination for both sets $S_1$ and $S_2$?

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase this question and explain what it is exactly that you're asking?

Comment: Apologies, I haven't done math since high school so I am very rusty. I will try to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: $\binom{32}{8}$

Or $\binom{16}{4}^2$ to keep k=4 between the sets.